# Invoke Windows 8.1 using URI

Tags: microsoft-metro, uri, windows-8.1

I am facing a problem while invoking windows 8.1(metro style) without launching.

It works fine when launch app first and then call it using URI. it works fine . it calls OnActivated method when it launched.

but if you don't launch the app and call it using uri, then it doesn't display anything.

Does anyone have faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the arguments at OnActivate(). I.e.:

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{

    // Blah, blah, blah ...

    protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Check to see if the app was activated via a protocol
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {
            var protocolArgs = (ProtocolActivatedEventArgs)args;

            // Do something with 'protocolArgs.Uri'.
        }
    }
}
```